# Bash get array members from one array with index value from other array

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm writing a script using multiple dialog screens in bash. One of the functions of the script should be killing specific processes. I load all my PID values in one array called pid:

```
pid = ('1234' '1233' '1232' '1231' '1230')
```

Then I present the user with a dialog checklist that contains a list of the processes.
After they select some of them dialog returns the checklist entry number, for example 0,2,4.

My initial plan was to store the selected entries in a second array and then use it to get specific PID's from the first array, but so far, nothing I've tried worked, in this case that would be: 1234, 1232, 1230. So I can kill those specific processes.

Does anyone have a better solution? I want the easiest way of killing processes based on selections made by the user at the dialog checklist.

Here is the function in question:

```
stop_tunnel() {

local tunnels
local pid
declare -a tunnels
declare -a pid

#this is executed on a remote system in the real script
ps aux | grep -w ssh > $_temp

awk -F "ssh" '{print "ssh" $2}' $_temp > $_temp1
awk '{print $2}' $_temp > $_temp2

IFS='
'
tunnels=( $( < $_temp1 ) )
pid=( $( < $_temp2 ) )

dialog --checklist "Select tunnel to stop:" 10 72 0 \
                   0 "${tunnels[0]}" off \
                   1 "${tunnels[1]}" off \
                   2 "${tunnels[2]}" off \
                   3 "${tunnels[3]}" off \
                   4 "${tunnels[4]}" off \
                   2>$_temp

nr=$( < $_temp )

dialog --title " Tunnel stop " --msgbox "\nYou stopped these tunnels: ${nr[@]}" 6 44

}
```

The nr array holds the users selection. And I wanted to use that to pull specific members out of the pid array.

Comment: What you suggest sounds feasible.  The other main option is to return the list of selected processes as a single string with spaces separating them, and then invoke `kill $process_list` without any double quotes around the `$process_list`.  This involves changing the 'dialog checklist', of course.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jonathan. That would definitely be a good way, although I am having trouble with using my second array to select specific PID's from the first one. Just to be clear, the list containing the processes has only the full command of the process including switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Select** might be what you need:

```
select p in ${pid[@]} ; do   echo "kill" $p && break; done
```

Note that blanks around the assignment won't work:

```
# wrong:
pid = ('1234' '1233' '1232' '1231' '1230')
# right:
pid=('1234' '1233' '1232' '1231' '1230')
```

To allow to kill multiple processes in sequence:

```
select p in ${pid[@]} ; do
  if [[ -n $p ]]
     then echo "kill" $p
     else break
  fi
done
1) 1234
2) 1233
3) 1232
4) 1231
5) 1230
#? 3
kill 1232
#? 4
kill 1231
#? 6
```

The **echo** is of course just for testing.

A hint for the user, that an invalid index will terminate the process killing seems appropriate.  A second approach could be an explicit termination case:

```
pid=('1234' '1233' '1232' '1231' '1230' 'terminate')
```

which you would handle with the break.

If you just want to iterate over the selections, being made:

```
sel=(0 2 4) 
for n in ${sel[@]} ; do echo kill ${pid[$n]}; done
```

### update towards you comment:

I don't have dialog installed, but I guess `zenity` is similar. There you capture the output of a list seleciton:

```
selection=($(zenity --list --text "kill something" --multiple --column "kill" --separator " " --checklist --column ps TRUE foo FALSE bar FALSE baz TRUE fozboa))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but currently I don't have a problem with killing processes, but with selecting only the PID's from the first array based on the users selection on the checklist.

Comment: @f10bit: I added two lines how to kill in pid, based on sel, if both are arrays. Is it that?

Comment: thank you user unknown, that seems to be the push my braindead self needed at this point, now if only I can figure out how to store the users selections properly in the nr array instead of them all being in the 0 index like they are now, probably IFS issue :)

Comment: I updated again. Maybe dialog is similar enough to zenity. I don't have dialog installed. Without `--separator " "`, the output would be foo|bar|baz (imho a bad design decision). With bash replacing ${sel//|/ } you could transfrom it to blanks, useful for array definition.

Comment: Found the dialog switch I was looking for: --separate-output

"For checklist widgets, output result one line at a time, with no quoting.  This facilitates parsing by another program."

As far as I can tell, it's working, thanks again for all the input!